# MariaDB running indefinitely on inner join with count

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb, count

I am currently experiencing a very, very weird issue with a query in MariaDB. Our server experiences a "504 Gateway Timeout" quite often after a database upgrade, and I was investigating the issue.

After tracking it down and simplifying the query, I've come up with the following query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(trace)
from traces
INNER JOIN banner on banner.banner_short = trace
```

**This query does not work. It just runs indefinitely, not returning. This is most probably what causes the gateway timeout, since PHP cannot respond in time.**

Now onto the more interesting part. Why does this query not run? If I change `COUNT(trace)` to `*` to select all the fields, it works just fine. Also, removing the `INNER JOIN` solves the issue as well.

**How does an unused `INNER JOIN` in combination with `COUNT` affect a query like this? Why won't it complete?**

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN <query>` outputs for both of your queries (the one that works and the one that doesn't, and it will give you 80% of the information you need.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` counts the amount of records. It's fast. `COUNT(field)` counts the amount of records which contain non-NULL value in the `field`.

Comment: @jynus the output of the explain statement is exactly the same for both queries: hastebin.com/yawaluratu

Comment: @Akina I didn't change `COUNT(field)` to `COUNT(*)`, I changed it to `*` to select all records, not count them. That worked just fine.

Comment: Your `SELECT COUNT(trace) from traces INNER JOIN banner on banner.banner_short = trace` is equal logically to `SELECT COUNT(*) from traces INNER JOIN banner on banner.banner_short = trace where trace is not null` except that in your query server additionally checks all record's `trace` fields for a non-null whereas in my query it will not check at all I think (`trace` field is not nullable, is it?). Again when you replace COUNT funcion with asterisk server do not need to check any field for nulls.

Comment: @Akina The same query with `COUNT(*)` also runs indefinitely. I have no idea what's going on, but I don't think that the field I am counting is the issue.

Comment: As asked above, show EXPLAIN of your query. And additionally - table's DDLs.

Comment: @Akina The `EXPLAIN` you asked for is already posted above. Please refer to the link I provided.

Comment: *Please refer to the link I provided.* It was extremely difficult to copy it and paste into the question as a text? with 4-space indent for to keep formatting... Now please show DDLs (paste them into the question text as a code) - but I already think that there is no any (suitable) indices in your tables, and you must create proper ones to optimize your query.

Comment: @NikxDa - What table is `trace` in?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.  What version of MySQL/MariaDB?